# Calling a function that throws exceptions from a noexcept function

Tags: c++, c++11

I am using a library from a 3rd party whose source code I have no control over. The library has a function (say `foo()`) which may throw exceptions under certain conditions.

If the function (in my code) that I am calling `foo` from can guarantee that the conditions under which `foo()` will throw will not be met presently would it make sense for me to declare my function noexcept and thus save on the compiler unwinding routines and thus make the code faster?

I have not done any performance testing to see if it would be faster. I am just checking in to see if this is a good design. The reason why I ask this is because in future the library code could change and possibly throw exceptions in cases that I may not have handled in my code. If this happens then my application would terminate. So from a design perspective is what I am thinking of doing a good move? Or should I just handle the exceptions in my code and not propagate them out and leave the function as noexcept? The callers of my function wouldn't be able to do anything meaningful with these exceptions. So I don't want to propagate them out or wrap them into an application specific exception either.

Comment: If the library changes in the future, and your code do not handle new exceptions, it crashes anyway, unless you catch all exceptions and ignore them.

Comment: If you declare your func as noexept, any throwing will end in terminate. There is no compiler nor linker warning. As this, there is no c++ feature which lets you safely declare any func as noexept/nothrow whatever. For my point of view this is a "no feature" of c++, because you can't use it without taking much care your self or using external tools to check what will happened in the complete call tree. But I did not know any such tool. As this: Don't use it if you will not run by accident in program termination.

Comment: Premature optimisation is the root of all evil.

Comment: *"to declare my function `noexcept` and thus save on the compiler unwinding routines and thus make the code faster?"* Notice that optimization with `noexcept` is limited. Your function has to handle exception to call `std::terminate`. function calling your function might indeed do some optimization, but mostly require that all statements are `noexcept` too.